# what are the best websites to do a Literature Review?

Tags: graduate-admissions, research-process, graduate-school, literature-review

I have just started my master degree. so literature review is completely new to me. I want to search for papers published in high-rank conferences and journal with high impact number. Apart from Google Scholar what are the other websites?

I should add this to my Question: 
Thanks for useful comments. But unfortunately, I don't have access to the library.

Comment: Web of science good for sci journal

Comment: Check the search engine of your library if they offer one. This will mostly search all the databases and journals the have subscribed. Anyway, asking your library for information or even seminars they offer regarding literature search is a great start.

Comment: @nikki2 You are a student and don´t have access to the library? Where are you from? (Maybe surfing the web / the databases from within the univesity network is already sufficient to get access. Many sites give access if you use a IP address associated with a university.)

Comment: You can't do a lit review without access to a library.

Comment: I'm on mobile so I can't link it, but there's currently a Hot Network Question about how unimportant impact factor is in literature searches that you may want to check out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I tend to use what I call a *bootstrapping* method for doing literature reviews. I start with a paper that is relevant to the topic area. I then work backwards and forwards from that paper. I pull all the relevant papers that the paper cites and use a website (doesn't really matter which one) to find all the relevant papers that cite the paper. I then repeat the process for each of those papers. As my literature search is nearing the end, I try and look at the webpages of the key authors in the area to see if they published something obscure.

The reason the website does not really matter is that by going backwards and forwards you are leveraging the literature searches that were done for all the other papers. As you are not searching for key words, but rather by citations, the search engine is not as critical. What matters is if the relevant papers are published in places that the search engine indexes. If something is not indexed in the major academic databases, is not referenced by other authors, and was written by someone peripheral to the field, then, unfortunately, the work will probably get missed.

Comment: I call that snowball procedure and reverse snowball procedure, respectively. It's very efficient, but one downside is that it may introduce bias if you are looking unknowingly only at one big cluster within a network with several clusters.

Answer (score 4):

My students never use the online library tools (despite the fact that I always suggest this to them as a first resource), but that would be a good place to look for literature in your field. If you go to the library, the librarian will show you how to use it and most universities will allow you to access all online materials from off-campus.

Also, impact factor is not the best indicator of the quality of research that should be included in a literature review. Impact factor relates to how much work from that journal is cited. There are some journals with a very specific focus and therefore do not get cited often, but the research is very high quality. Also, some researchers decide to publish in journals with lower or no impact factors to get their work published more quickly or to target a specific audience. Their research may still be very high in quality.

Comment: Thanks for useful comments. But unfortunately, I don't access to the library.

Comment: @nikki2 I would recommend adding this to your question, as many answers assume you can

Answer (score 3):

The most valuable advice on literature searching I ever received was *to book an appointment with a research librarian*. It is literally their job to know how to find papers in the literature.

I would start there, as the answer to this question will vary wildly by field and geographic location.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the really good answer of @Nicole Ruggiano you can have a look at the [Wikipedia list of academic databases and search engines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_academic_databases_and_search_engines).